# Using sequelize with TypeScript: How to join tables with additional attributes?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, associations

I am trying to join tables using sequelize in Typescript like is described [here](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/associations/belongs-to-many.js%7EBelongsToMany.html) for JavaScript. However, the [docs on typescript](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html) are severely limited. I can't seem to find a way to join tables with additional attributes. The problem arises when I try to add the functions to the model for the association like

```
public addGroup!: BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin<Group, Group['fullName'], userGroup>;
```

Where `userGroup` should be the table with the additional attribute, which I currently defined as

```
/**
 * userGroup is the function relating users to groups via userGroup.
 */
const userGroup: any = db.define('user_group', {
    func: DataTypes.STRING
});
```

However, the `BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin` takes only 2 parameters. The inspiration for what i currently did was via [this article](https://vivacitylabs.com/setup-typescript-sequelize/). But unfortunately it does not seem to work for me yet.

Comment: Since you know that `BelongsToManyAddAssociationMixin` only accepts two generic parameters, why pass three?

Comment: The article and documentation pass 3 so its weird xD but i went on to work with the sequelize-typescript library (works quite nicely i must say) which gets rid of these functions. On to different problems now :)